# php problem: strpos function not working

Tags: php, substr

why is the following php code not working:

```
$string = "123";
$search = "123";

if(strpos($string,$search))
{
    echo "found";
}else{
    echo "not found";
}
```

as $search is in $string - shouldn't it be triggered as found?

Comment: See the first example on http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php. You need === to compare it

Comment: To eschew that issue, learn to use `strstr` instead.

Answer (score 8):

This is mentioned in the [Manual: strpos()](http://php.net/strpos)

> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE, such as 0 or "". Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

In your case the string is found at the index `0` and in php `0 == false`

The solution is to just use the strict comparator

```
echo strpos($string,$search) === false
     ? "not found"
     : "found";
```

Another one

```
echo is_int(strpos($string,$search))
     ? "found"
     : "not found";
```

Or something ... lets say interesting :D Just for illustration. I don't recommend this one.

```
echo strpos('_' . $string,$search) // we just shift the string 1 to the right
     ? "found"
     : "not found";
```

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because the search string is being found at position 0.
Try

`if(strpos($string,$search) !== FALSE)`

instead of

`if(strpos($string,$search))`

Comment: `(1 != false) === true`. In fact `($x != false) === ($x == true) === ((boolean) $x)` for every `$x`. Thus both code snippets are identical.

Comment: @KingCrunch: so would if(strpos($string,$search) !== FALSE) be correct?

Comment: @OzairKafray it worked for me using `!== false`, it doesn't if I use `!= false`

Comment: @user1301428: This was to highlight the difference between ===/!== and ==/!=, different things would work in different situations. To be sure what to use one should read the documentation for a function carefully and then assess his/her situation.

Comment: @OzairKafray if I understand it correctly, when the needle is found at the beginning of the haystack, then !== should always be used, but I might be wrong

Comment: You are right. I am wondering what would have got me the first vote. Updated now.

Answer (score 2):

`strpos` returns the first offset where `$search` was found - `0`. `0` in turn evaluates to `false`. Therefore the if fails.

If `$search` was not found, `strpos` returns `FALSE`. First check the return value for `!== FALSE`, and then check the offset.

Thanks to everyone who pointed this out in the comments.

see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: ... which is why the standard practice is to check whether `strpos(...) === FALSE`. See the big warning on the man page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: Correct explanation, but it's better to strictly check if itis' not false (!== false)

Comment: `strpos($string,$search)>=0` does not work as expected, because `(false >= 0) === true`.

Comment: You are of course correct - you really should check `!== FALSE` !

Answer (score 2):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

> This function may return Boolean
>   FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to
>   FALSE, such as 0 or "". Please read
>   the section on [Booleans](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) for more
>   information. Use [the === operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)
>   for testing the return value of this
>   function.

In your example, you should use

```
$string = "123";
$search = "123";

if ( false !== strpos( $string, $search ) ) {
    echo "found";
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

strpos returns the numeric position of the string you want to search for if it finds it. So in your case, you want to be doing this instead:

```
$search = "123";
$string = "123";
if (strpos($string,$search)===false) { echo "not found"; }
else { echo "found"; }
```

basically it returns a false if it doesn't find your string

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
<?php

$string = "123";

$find = "123";

$strpos = strpos($string, $find);

if($strpos || $strpos === (int)0) {
    echo "Found it!";
} else {
    echo "Not Found!";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well documented issue explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). strpos is simply returning '0'